# CSS progress bar with smoothed adjustments

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm writing a countdown bar which sometimes needs to be adjusted from js.  Setting currentTime directly is too jarring -- I'd like to transition to new value. I have a working prototype which abuses playbackRate to quickly jump to the new spot, but it's hacky and doesn't allow fancier motion like easing. Is there a better way to achieve a similar effect?

https://jsfiddle.net/isaacly/byac2gqe

```js
var totalClockMs = 6000;  // set this to "total" clock time.
var transitionMs = 100;

var anim = document.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0].animate(
  [
    { transform: 'scaleX(1)' },
    { transform: 'scaleX(0)' }
  ], {
    duration: totalClockMs,
    fill: "both"
  }
);
anim.pause();

var i = 1;
var desired;
var callback;
var callbackFn;
$('#change').click(function() {
  if (i++ % 2 === 0) {
    anim.pause();
    var current = anim.currentTime;
    // Example of setting bar after move finishes, in this case adding 500ms.
    anim.playbackRate = -500 / transitionMs;
    anim.play();
    callbackFn = () => {
      //console.log(current - 500 - anim.currentTime);
      callback = undefined;
      anim.pause();
      anim.currentTime = current - 500;
      anim.playbackRate = 1;
    };
    callback = setTimeout(callbackFn, transitionMs);
  } else {
    if (callback !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(callback);
      callbackFn();
    }
    anim.play();
  }
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #e5e9eb;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #90ee90;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress">
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="change">Pause/Play</button>
```